# Can't install latest NodeJS on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, node.js

I run Debian 9.3. I went to the NodeJS [website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) to see how to install NodeJS v9.X on my machine and ran the code provided.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But the terminal spit out this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.8.2~dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My machine is stuck with NodeJS v4.8.2 and NPM v1.4.21.

How do I upgrade to the latest NodeJS and NPM?

**UPDATE**

I followed @GAD3R's instructions. It still installs v4.8.2. Here's what I get after running GAD3R's commands then running `sudo apt install nodejs`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libuv1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libuv1 nodejs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,524 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package libuv1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 141225 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libuv1_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuv1:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_4.8.2~dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libuv1:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up nodejs (4.8.2~dfsg-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
```

When I run `update-alternatives --config nodejs`, the terminal prints `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for nodejs`

==

When I run `apt-cache policy nodejs`, I get this...

```
nodejs:
  Installed: 4.8.2~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 4.8.2~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     9.3.0-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch/main amd64 Packages
     8.9.3~dfsg-2 1
          1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian experimental/main amd64 Packages
     6.12.0~dfsg-2 500
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.8.2~dfsg-1 990
        990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

==

I ran `sudo /etc/apt/preferences`, which did not exist until now, and wrote this in it:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=experimental
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: *
Pin: release n=unstable
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: *
Pin: release n=stable
Pin-Priority: 500
```

I re-ran the commands from GAD3R's post, but still Debian installed v4.8.2 of `nodejs` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.8.2 version is installed through `apt` from the [main repo](https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/nodejs).

run:

```
apt purge nodejs
apt install lsb-release
apt install -y nodejs
```

Verify the installed `nodjs` version:

```
node --version
v9.3.0
```

The `npm` version:

```
npm --version
5.5.1
```

The problem come from the pin priority , pin the stable release to `500`

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=experimental 
Pin-Priority: 100
```

Unstable:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=unstable
Pin-Priority: 100
```

And the stable:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=stable
Pin-Priority: 500
```

The problem is solved by:

> Open synaptic , search for nodejs , press CTRL + E then choose the `nodsource1` version then apply changes.

Comment: Still gives me the same `nodejs` version, but no `npm`.

Comment: @Username can you add the output of `update-alternatives --config nodejs` to the question , please.

Comment: Running that command, the terminal prints "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for nodejs"

Comment: @Username Please check your [Pin-Priority](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) , maybe it is configured to install the packages from the stable release. please add the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs`

Comment: Added the output to my question

Comment: @Username i have update my answer.

Comment: What would I write in `/etc/apt/preferences`?

Comment: See under `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` maybe you have more than 1 file

Comment: @Username Are you able to modify the pin priority ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have no files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`. Do I write the pin preferences in a file there? If so, what do I name the file?

Comment: @Username You should edit the existing file `/etc/apt/preferences`

Comment: That file did not exist. I made it. Debian still installs v4.8.2. See edit to my question.

Comment: @Username did you have synaptic packager installed?

Comment: Yes I have that package installed

Comment: @Username Open synaptic , search for nodejs , press CTRL + E then choose the `nodsource1` version then apply changes.

Comment: That did it for installing v9.3.0 of `nodejs` package

Comment: When I'm trying to install a new package with `npm` after followed this procedure above  I've got this error message : `npm ERR! Invalid argument: family must be 4 or 6`. Should I open a new ask

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on a Pi3 Model B (with raspbian stretch 9.4). First I tried to force installation of nodejs-v8 by specifying the version in the apt-get command: `apt install nodejs=8.11.2~dfsg-1+b1`. This did not work for me because it resulted in unmet dependencies:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nodejs : Depends: libnghttp2-14 (>= 1.25.0) but 1.18.1-1 is to be installed
         Depends: libuv1 (>= 1.18.0) but 1.9.1-3 is to be installed
         Recommends: nodejs-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The accepted answer of GAD3R did also not work for me.

However when I ran `apt-cache policy nodejs` I got this:

```
nodejs:
  Installed: 4.8.2~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 4.8.2~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     8.11.4-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch/main armhf Packages
     8.11.2~dfsg-1+b1 750
        750 https://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/raspbian/raspbian testing/main armhf Packages
 *** 4.8.2~dfsg-1 900
        900 https://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Forcing the installation of nodejs from the testing repository:

```
apt-get install nodejs -t testing
```

This worked like a charm!

```
node -v
v8.11.2
```

Comment: The problem is that with Username's output, the 9.3 is also in the main repo based on the output. (`-t experimental` would at least install 8.9.3). A pin with [origin](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html) instead should work...